# Why does Analytics say "no data available"?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

Anyone know why No data is available from the last five months?
I didn't change anything on my site. Thanks a million
Ascanio

[image]

Comment: Is the Google Analytics code still available on your webpages?

Comment: Hi Toon, I believe it is as all the other data still shows up

Comment: You may have to re-link the GA account to your Search Console. I believe this is where the data comes from.

Comment: This is interesting. Whenever I send a pageview or event hit to your site, it does a 307 redirect. Just my observation. Not sure if there's any bearing on anything related to what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

The data in that report, acquisition > Search engine optimization, is pulled in from Google Search Console, and you have to associate a GA account with a Search Console for it to work.

I'm guessing the association with you Search Console account has been removed, or been associated with another account.

More info here:  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006?hl=en&ref_topic=2370569&vid=1-635772796444585896-784166504